# what is "ssl/tls protocol filtering" in Eset Internet Security, and do I need it?

Tags: email, thunderbird, ssl, anti-virus, eset

Recently, Thunderbird upgraded to version 78.4.0, from version 68.
After the update, I couldn't receive any email, from any server whatsoever.

After considrerable reserach, I disabled "ssl/tls protocol filtering" in Eset Internet Security. Now I can receive emails without any issue.

However my doubt remains: have I broken something?
What does "ssl/tls protocol filtering" actually do? Is it something useful? Should I turn it back on, and search for the right settings, so I can receive emails but leave the setting on as a whole?

Comment: It breaks secure traffic by allowing ESET to otherwise scan encrypted connections.  In other works it allows ESET to scan the emails received.  It’s primarily designed to scan the HTTPS connections, by breaking the security, and using an insecure certificate signed by ESET instead of the certificate that is supposed to be used.  It’s a useless feature,

Comment: @Ramhound Why do you think ESET issued certificate is insecure? Any details on that?
Also why scanning of incoming content should be useless feature? Why would one install security software if it should not scan content downloaded from the internet (most of it is going through SSL nowadays).

Comment: @ge0rdi - Because it literally breaks secured HTTP connections.  It allows a third-party to scan your encrypted traffic.  I have no doubt ESET uploads some of that data to themselves as in the name of improving their engine or in the name of security. **Don’t get me wrong any security product that scans encrypted secure traffic is insecure it’s not limited to ESET**

Comment: @Ramhound Do you have any more info on allowing third-party to scan your encrypted traffic? I though ESET generated certificate is unique per-machine.
Regarding uploading data, don't you think there are other sensitive information on machine that security software has access to already? Installing security software is about trust. If you don't trust your security vendor then why to use their products in first place.

Comment: There is a place for products like ESET,  however, I would rather generate my own certificates and use a proxy to protect a corporate network.  It’s clear you disagree with my assertion that scanning secure traffic is breaking encrypted connections like https.  The certificate might be generated per machine doesn’t change the fact it still breaks the security

Comment: @Ramhound I disagree with your _It’s a useless feature_ comment.
Breaking encrypted communication is not ideal, but without it security product may be unable to provide reasonable protection (as most of HTTP communication is encrypted these days).

Comment: @Ramhound So, do I understand right that with the filtering off, it means my AV won't be able to warn me of virus-prone email attachments, downloads or phishing websites, since it can't access the encrypted connection?

Comment: @1NN - Your AV could scan your emails if you used an add-on for whatever client you used.  You should scan the emails as they are received on the email sever itself.  You shouldn't lower the security of the connection to the client/server to scan emails, scan the emails as they are received, plently of options there.